# In Auctioneer, is there a way to set a default markup price when there is no competition?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, mods

I use auctioneer all the time, and when posting items I have it set to undercut my competitors by 1%.

However, if there is no competition for a particular item, it simply sets the default to the market price.

**Is there an option in Auctioneer to set it so if there is no competition, raise the default markup price** by 100% or by 50g (for example)?

---

Basically, if there is no competition on an item, I might as well put it on the AH for a high price, rather than market price.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if Auctioneer has *no* pricing data for an item at all, it will mark up the vendor price by 300%.

Obviously this is much too low for most items...

You can change this percentage in Auctioneer's [Pricing](http://wiki.norganna.org/Auctioneer/Pricing) options page. But there's no option to set a *fixed* price.

Though, generally, for items that there's no scan data for, I usually want to look them up myself.

You may also want to consider using another addon such as TradeSkillMaster, which can obtain more sources of pricing data (such as from The Undermine Journal) and which will reduce or eliminate the occurrence of not knowing how much to price an item for.

Answer (score 0):

You could set it to a fixed price. Auction one item, scan the AH and change it to default mark up price. You should have an artificial mark up price when there's no competition then.